# Is there a set of better rules for Monopoly?

Tags: house-rules, monopoly

Monopoly is pretty infamous for sucking.

Has anyone ever reconstructed the rules from the ground up to make it a better game? If it were a video game I'd ask for a total conversion mod or something like that.

I know there are lots of house rules and other options in the rule manual and to be found online, but I'm looking for a comprehensive overhaul that keeps the idea of the game but is more fun.

I tried searching the internet, but all I can find are references to McDonald's Monopoly.

Comment: From everything I have ever read, if you follow the actual rules and don't bring in any house rules it is a lot better game. It is just that the house rules destroy the game.

Comment: Have you actually played Monopoly ***by the official rules***? Monopoly is only famous for "sucking" because of too many and inappropriate house rules, intended to ensure that *the kiddies* never lose by extending the game indefinitely.

Comment: Hm. Well, that's certainly an interesting perspective. I don't recall all the times I've ever played Monopoly, but probably not.

Comment: House rules definitely make the game worse, but the official rules for Monopoly still lead to a quick-to-unbalance, slow-to-finish game with a largely static strategy. It's not **only** bad because of house rules.